# Memory consumption during parsing of YAML with yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, json, yaml-cpp

I am developing Qt application for embedded system with limited memory. I need to receive a few megabytes of JSON data and parse it as fast as possible and without using too much memory.

I was thinking about using streams:

JSON source (HTTP client) ---> ZIP decompressor ---> YAML parser ----> objects mapped to database

Data will arrive from network much slower than I can parse it.

1. How much memory yaml-cpp need to parse 1MB of data?
2. I would like already parsed raw data from decompressor and internal memory used for that data by YAML parser to be released as soon as object mapped to database is created. Is it possible?
3. Does yaml-cpp support asynchronous parsing? So as soon as JSON object is parsed, I can store it in database without waiting for full content from HTTP source.

Comment: How many object are you receiving? How many properties in each object? Average size of each property? I yaml-cpp capable of parsing one object at a time as they come in? And are you receiving JSON or YAML?

Comment: I can receive a few thousands of objects. It can be easily 7MB of text. I use JSON which is a subset of YAML 1.2 and can be parsed with yaml-cpp.

I don't know if yaml-cpp is capable of parsing one object at a time as they come in, as this is part of my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have memory constraints and your data is already in JSON, you should use a low-memory JSON parser instead of a YAML parser. Try [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) - although I'm not sure what their support for streaming is (since JSON doesn't have the concept of documents).

yaml-cpp *is* designed for streaming, so it won't block if there are documents to parse but the stream is still open; however, there is an [outstanding issue](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=148) in yaml-cpp where it reads more than a single document at a time, so it really isn't designed for extremely low memory usage.

As for how much memory it takes to parse 1 MB of data, it is probably on the order of 3 MB (the raw input stream, plus the parsed stream, plus the resulting data structure), but it may vary dramatically depending on what kind of data you're parsing.

Comment: Can you suggest some C/C++ libraries that would fit the purpose? I had a quick search in Ubuntu repo and didn't find anything suitable. Also are you able to answer my 3 questions? From what you are saying I guess answer to 2 and 3 is "no". How about te first question?

Comment: I came back to optimization of this piece of functionality. I checked VmPeak of my process before parsing and after, it turned out that VmPeak increased by 16MB. This result was achieved with gzipped JSON file of 84kB, which is almost 1MB after decompression. In comparison to this RapidJSON insitu parsing gave me increase of 3MB.